# Writing Latex in Ipython output

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Consider the following lines in a IPython notebook:

```
 B=1.0e5   # in Gauss
 fce = 1.80e6 * B
 print "Electron gyrofrequency $f_{ce}$= %0.5e " %(fce)
```

I cannot get $f_{ce}$ to print in its latex form. I also tried:

```
     from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex 
     display ("Electron gyrofrequency" + Math(r'f_{ce}') + "= %0.5e " %(fce))
```

I got an error:

```
 TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Math' objects
```

Comment: have you tried `Latex("Electron gyrofrequency $f_{ce}$= %0.5e " %fce)`

Comment: That worked. Please make it an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the full latex string by passing it to the `Latex` constructor:

```
from IPython.display import Latex

B=1.0e5   # in Gauss
fce = 1.80e6 * B 

Latex("Electron gyrofrequency $f_{ce}$= %0.5e " % fce)
```

Comment: I just asked one more question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365927/ipython-output-missing