# How do I get a newline in a Ipython output

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

Consider the following input in a IPython notebook:

```
mu = 39.95   
Z=1
Latex(r"Atomic Mass: $\quad \mu$= %0.5e Hz" %(mu))
Latex(r"Charge state: $\quad z$= %0.5e" %(Z))
```

My question has two parts.

**(A) Missing output**

From above source, Surprisingly I got the following result:

```
 Charge state:  z = 1.00000e+00
```

What happened to the first line (i.e the value of $mu$ was not printed)?

**(B) Missing newline**

I was however able to get the result using the following:

```
      Latex(r"Atomic Mass: $\quad \mu$= %0.5e Hz   " %(mu) + r"Charge state: $\quad z$= %0.5e" %(Z))
```

But now, I need a newline in the above. How does one do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the notebook only renders the last value obtained in a cell. Use `IPython.display.display` as an augmented `print` function to display several things:

```
from IPython.display import Latex, display

mu = 39.95   
Z=1
display(Latex(r"Atomic Mass: $\quad \mu$= %0.5e Hz" % mu))
display(Latex(r"Charge state: $\quad z$= %0.5e" % Z))
```